# Titanium 3.0 shows xcode not found

Tags: ipad, ios6, titanium

I am using `Titanium 2.1.3 SDK` and I have updated my Titanium to 3.0 and installed `Titanium 3.0 SDK`.

After installing the latest SDK and selecting 3.0 SDK in `tiapp.xml` and when I try to run my project it shows ERROR `xcode not found`.

But the xcode is present and installed in my system and its version is `4.5.1`.

After that I try to select the 2.1.3 SDK in `tiapp.xml` and try to run the project but now it doesn't load and shows this error.

```
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/p132/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.3.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1325, in main
execute_xcode("iphonesimulator%s" % link_version,["GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=__LOG__ID__=%s DEPLOYTYPE=development TI_DEVELOPMENT=1 DEBUG=1 TI_VERSION=%s %s %s" % (log_id,sdk_version,debugstr,kroll_coverage)],False)
File "/Users/p132/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.3.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1231, in execute_xcode
output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
File "/Users/p132/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.3.GA/iphone/run.py", line 41, in run
sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 65
```

I tried to remove the Titanium SDK 3.0 but the problem is as it is.

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the similar problem. Manage to solve after following the instruction by typing the below in terminal:

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: I will try this, but before installing 3.0 I am able to create build of my ipad application but after that It is not creating the build. Do you know how to solve this?